# Can Kohana 3's validation errors inherit?

Tags: php, validation, kohana, kohana-3

I've created a bunch of errors in a file under `APPPATH/messages/validate.php` with a bunch of *common* messages such as...

```
return array(
    'not_empty'    => ':field must not be empty.',
    'matches'      => ':field must be the same as :param1',
    'regex'        => ':field does not match the required format',
    'exact_length' => ':field must be exactly :param1 characters long',
    'min_length'   => ':field must be at least :param1 characters long',
    'max_length'   => ':field must be less than :param1 characters long',
    'in_array'     => ':field must be one of the available options',
    'digit'        => ':field must be a digit',
    'email'        => 'You must enter a valid email.',
    'name'         => 'You must enter your name.',
    'enquiry'      => 'You must enter your enquiry.',
    'captcha' => array (
        'Captcha::valid' => 'The characters you entered did not match the image. Please try again.',
        'not_empty' => 'You must enter the characters from the image.'
    ) 
);
```

This works great when I get errors like `$errors = $post->errors('validate')`.

Is there a way to use these errors as *base* errors, and if I have a separate form which needs more, I can use a separate file with only the differences in it, for example it may look like

```
return array(
    'permissions'    => 'Please agree to the permissions',
);
```

So obviously, any `email` error message will come from `validate.php` (inherited), but any `permissions` error will come from the new file with the error definition for `permissions`.

I named the file `validate.php` because the inherit behaviour seems to work with the `system` folder and that is what it is called under `SYSPATH/messages/validate.php` (see it on [GitHub](http://github.com/kohana/core/blob/master/messages/validate.php)).

Can my error messages inherit from a base file, or should I just copy all the error messages per form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance works automatically, follow this pattern:

1. Search for a field+error specific message in the given file
2. Search for a field+default message in the given file
3. Search for a generic message in the given file
4. Search for a generic message in `validate` file

So, if you overload the `validate` file and change the default messages, then inheritance will work as expected.

Comment: Hey Shadowhand, thanks for the answer. Do you mean change `validate` in the system folder? Because when I copied that `validate` file into the `APPPATH/messages` folder, IIRC, it didn't work.

Comment: It should be placed in `APPPATH/messages`.

Answer (score 4):

common errors: APPPATH/messages/validate.php

```
return array(
    'email'        => 'You must enter a valid email.',
    'name'         => 'You must enter your name.',
    'enquiry'      => 'You must enter your enquiry.',
    'captcha' => array (
        'Captcha::valid' => 'The characters you entered did not match the image. Please try again.',
        'not_empty' => 'You must enter the characters from the image.'
    )
);
```

specific errors: APPPATH/messages/specific.php

```
return array(
    'permissions'    => 'Please agree to the permissions',
);
```

Kohana uses these sequence to find the message: APPPATH/messages/specific.php, APPPATH/messages/validate.php and SYSPATH/messages/validate.php

```
print_r(validate->errors('specific'));
```

Answer (score 3):

without "hacks":

```
    $orm->values($form[$this->name])->check();

    $not_model_errors = Validate::factory(array())->rule(NULL, 'permissions_rules'); // doesn't matter what args you send here, just meet the vartype
    // add test error
    $not_model_errors->error(NULL, 'test_error', array());

    $this->template->errors = $orm->validate()->errors('validation') + $not_model_errors->errors('permissions');
```

your model shouldn't validate your businesses logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is hacky, but it works!

```
$commonErrors = include APPPATH .  'messages/validate.php';

$errors =  array(
    'permission' => array(
        'not_empty' => 'You must give permission to continue.'
    )
);

return array_merge($commonErrors, $errors);
```

Basically, it auto inherits the base rules for you!